# Android: customize DialogPreference Ok/Cancel buttons

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I cannot find a way to properly modify the *Ok/Cancel* buttons of the `DialogPreference`.

All the input dialogs in my app have the following button box:

[image]

This is what I can get in the `DialogPreference`:

[image]

not accetable, of course, as the buttons are swapped and with a horrible line in between.

What I do to apply the changes to the buttons is getting the `Dialog` int the `showDialog` method and setting a background to the layout:

```
public class RingtonePreference extends DialogPreference
{

    @Override
    protected void showDialog(Bundle state)
    {
        super.showDialog(state);

        Dialog d = getDialog();
        Utils.setAlertDialogButtons(getContext(), (AlertDialog)d, true);
    }

...

static public void setAlertDialogButtons(Context c, final AlertDialog alertDialog, final boolean hasNegative)
{
    try
    {
        int size = (int)c.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.btn_size);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(size, size);
        lp.setMargins(size/2, 5, size/2, 5);

        Button posBtn = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        LinearLayout tr = (LinearLayout)posBtn.getParent();
        tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fixed_buttons_background);

        posBtn.setText("");
        posBtn.setLayoutParams(lp);
        posBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_apply_selector);

        if (hasNegative)
        {
            Button negBtn = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            negBtn.setText("");
            negBtn.setLayoutParams(lp);
            negBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_back_selector);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("U", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm giving up but, before doing it, I ask here for help.
Giving up means "*leaving the original settings panel as it is*" (**horrible**):

[image]

so, please, help :)

Comment: In all Android versions since 4, positive buttons are always on the right and negative on the left so you may consider changing your custom dialogs to avoid confusing the user.

Comment: You can make `custom layout` for your dialog.

Comment: @BladeCoder: ok, I changed the parent of the app style from `android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar` to `android:Theme.Holo` and all the positive buttons are on the right side.
This also fixed the middle vertical line problem in the meaning that it's always there, not only in the settings panel, so it's not horrible anymore :).
If you write down an answer, I accept it as it fixed my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Clairvoyant´: `custom_layout` does have nothing to do with the button box, does it ?

Comment: @marco Did you test the preference screen on Lollipop as well? You may have some surprises.

Comment: @BladeCoder: yes, actually I'm testing only on API 19 and 21. Indeed, I should test some older version.

Comment: I think the easiest solution for this problem is to create a custom dialog based on `DialogFragment` ... that way you can customize the whole layout including buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you use the same theme for your standard app screens and Preferences screen to have consistent results.
2. Untested but should work: If you want to change the look and feel of the bottom buttons bar, what you could do is:

   - Override `setPositiveButtonText()` and `setNegativeButtonText()` in `DialogPreference` to make them no-ops so Android will not show the standard "ok" and "cancel" buttons bar.
   - Then in your overriden `showDialog()` method, after retrieving the `Dialog` like you do now, cast it to `AlertDialog` and call `setView()` to pass your custom footer layout. It will be shown at the same place as the OK/Cancel buttons, below the list.

Comment: I accept your answer, but only for the point 1 (even though setting a style to `DialogPreference` seems to be impossible) as the 2 is wrong.
I cannot override `AlertDialog.Builder.setNegativeButton` and `AlertDialog.Builder.setPositiveButton` (if you know how, please tell me) and `setView` has no effect.

Comment: I forgot the "Text" suffix, I meant overriding DialogPreference.setPositiveButtonText() and all its variants so that no button will be  shown.

Comment: I'm not talking about setting a style to a DialogPreference either, I'm taking about the Activity style: If your Activity has a Holo Dark theme, your dialogs will automatically have a Holo dark theme too by default.

Comment: Ah ok, but I was already doing that. The button's text was not a problem, it was just a matter of themes. BTW: "_back button_" set to the left has much more sense (in a left to right world) so, thanks again.